# java : How can i count number of even values in a list of numbers?

Tags: java

What this program supposed to do is : the user should input the number of values and then get the average of even numbers in the list of values. I am stuck on where i need to get the number of even values to get the average.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class SumOfEven {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n;
        int sum=0;
        double avg;
        String Numbers;
        int even;

        Numbers = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How Many Numbers In The List ??");
        n = Integer.parseInt( Numbers);

        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
        {
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                System.out.println("Number of Even Numbers In This List = "+i);
            }
        }

        for(int x=0;x<=n;x+=2){
           sum+=x;

        }

        avg=sum/n;
        System.out.println("sum of even numbers is =" +sum);
        System.out.println("avgerage of even numbers is =" +avg);

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the input format?

Comment: i don't want to list the even numbers ... instead i want to get how many even numbers in the list of values.

Comment: delete this question... please

Comment: JoptionPane? Are you expecting input from user on commandline or somewhere else?

Comment: If you have `n` successive integers then half of those (rounded down) will be even because every second integer is even.

Comment: Actually, it would be rounded up if the first number is even. So if you count `0` as even then you'll have to round up, if you don't then you'll have to round down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
int count = 0;
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
    if(i%2==0)
    {
       ++count;
    }
}

System.out.println("Number of Even Numbers In This List = "+count);
```

Comment: Look at comment under my answer.

Comment: This will work fine but it requires linear time (O(n)). This can however been solved in constant time (O(1)) as I show in my answer.

Comment: Look at comment below my answer.

Comment: but it should be ""int count=0;"" instead of ""int countOfEven=0;""

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter to get the number of even values in this way(c is the counter):

```
  int c = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
        {
           c++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of even number in list = "+ c);
```

Comment: is there any difference between your answer and mine.

Comment: Not really but when your answer was posted I was typing and didn't see your answer, I didn't copy your answer.

Comment: Since you want someone to accept your answer and because you answered first and your answer is correct I'll up vote it.

Comment: just returning the favour

Comment: I only want you to up vote my answer if you think it is worthy.

Comment: your answer is same as mine so how can i think that it is useless

Comment: I mean don't have the perception that I copied you.

Answer (score 0):

An even number has a remainder of zero when you divide it by two.

Hence, you can use something like:

```
if ((number % 2) == 0)
    evenCount++;
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Java 8** you can use the Stream API for this

```
long count = IntStream.range(0, n).filter(e -> e % 2 == 0).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the consecutive numbers 0..n then half of those will be even. So, assuming you count 0 as an even number:

```
int countOfEven = n/2 + 1;
```

If your numbers don't start with 0 but with a different value, you could do this:

```
int min = ...; // your minimum value
int max = ...; // your maximum value
int countOfEven = (max - min) / 2;
if(min % 2 == 0) {
    countOfEven += 1;
}
```